# jQuery: Trigger even when checkbox gets checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I am making a web app. In one part, I have a checklist dynamically generated with javascript.

I want to have a jQuery function executed when the checklist is checked.

Here is the code that dynamically generated the checklist:

```
var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
    checkbox.setAttribute("type","checkbox");
    checkbox.setAttribute("class", "tickbox");
    document.getElementById("sortable").appendChild(checkbox);
```

Here is the output HTML file on execution, that shows that the checkbox was actually created:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="tickbox">
```

I want to have a function executed when the box is checked. I have tried:

1.

```
 $('.tickbox').change(function () {
        alert("Here");
        if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
        alert("Yeah");
        }
```

2.

```
if($(.tickbox).is(':checked')){
      alert("Yeah!!!");
```

3.

```
$('.tickbox').each(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
      alert("Yeah!!!");
   }
   })
```

But nothing worked. What's wrong? What should I do?

Note: A lot of other javaScript and jQuery, including many other function calls are working completely fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said you have dynamically added checkbox so in order to add event handler to that DOM you has to use `.on()`.

**Example.**

```
$(document).on('change','.tickbox',function(){
   if($(this).is(':checked')){
      alert("Yeah!!!");
   }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this....

```
var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
    checkbox.setAttribute("type","checkbox");
    checkbox.setAttribute("class", "tickbox");
    document.getElementById("sortable").appendChild(checkbox);
$(".tickbox").click(function(){
   if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
       alert("checked");
   }
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7xY8Y/

Comment: Working fine when only one checkbox present but not with multiple. I am actually using multiple checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

for dynamically generated element you need to use on():

```
$(document).on("change",'.tickbox',function () {
   if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
   alert("Yeah");
 }
});
```

because your `tickbox` created dynamically then you need to bind event on document for class name tickbox for change event.